# Cordova reloading app when using camera

Tags: html, cordova, camera, cordova-plugins

I am using cordova 6.2.0, my app is restarting when i am trying to take picture. My code is :

```
var captureImage = function (e) {       

        navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
            quality: 60,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            correctOrientation: true,
            targetWidth: 768,
            targetHeight: 768,
        });

        function onSuccess(imageData) {
            imagecontainer.style.backgroundImage = "url('data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData + "')";
        }

        function onFail(message) {
           alert('Failed because: ' + message);
        }

    };
```

Comment: Need more details like in which device is it tested? Error trace in console?

Comment: I am using Samsung Galaxy Grand Neo (GT-19060i)

Comment: error trace in console?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use the Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI option instead of the one you used because it use less memory and your bug could be related to a memory issue.

Comment: Still having the same issue on my Samsung Galaxy Grand Neo (GT-19060i)